# Fabric.Js - Making the text that has been added to the canvas editable

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I seem to be having problems with making the text that is added to the canvas editable. I expect when you double click on the object for it to then change into an editable field but this doesn't seem to happen.

Below is the code that I am using and have read that you should be using for this to work:

```
    service.addEditableType = function () {
        service.canvas.add(new fabric.Text('Double tab here to type', {
            fontFamily: 'Delicious_500',
            fontSize: 30,
            left: 100,
            top: 100
        }));
    };
```

So this is what I'm using to add the text 'Double tab here to type' to the canvas. But if you then double click on the text it doesn't turn into an editable field.

Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 3):

Being a complete plonker...

I forgot the 'I' in 'Text'

The working code is as below:

```
service.addEditableType = function () {
    service.canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Double tab here to type', {
        fontFamily: 'Delicious_500',
        fontSize: 30,
        left: 100,
        top: 100
    }));
};
```